# Where are the cloth / fabric minifigure capes / cloaks in my set?

Tags: sets, minifigures, manufacturing, accessories, replacement-parts

I purchased The Mines of Moria (Lego Lord of the Rings item 9473) directly from The Big Store in Legoland, Florida.  When I opened it up at home, the capes / cloaks for Pippin and Boromir were missing.  No other parts appear to be missing, and the set did not appear tampered with.

I went to the LEGO website to report the missing items. The only items listed as "out of stock" on the website parts list were the capes and, as to be expected, the Cave Troll. While I can understand the fascination with the Cave Troll (it is a popular, obscure, and easy to rip off item from the set), I wonder if capes / cloaks going missing from sets is a chronic problem, as those being the only other items out of stock may indicate a larger issue.

Has anyone else experienced missing minifigure capes / cloaks, or is this issue unique to me?  Or, am I just seeing the "out of stock" message and imagining a problem where none exists?

Comment: Not all parts are available from the online page, especially rare or unusual parts - I'm not surprised the capes or parts of a Troll wouldn't be there. As for the parts missing in your box, well, if they're in the instructions, they should be in the box, period. Check their part IDs in the parts list at the end of the instructions, and call the customer service with that info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I found them.**

The capes were packaged in a small, unmarked, rectangular, white, cardboard box that was taped shut. Apparently, this little box came with the set, but someone else assumed it was filler trash and put it on our recycling queue.

Considering the capes are the only items out of stock besides the Cave Troll, it is possible others may be simply dismissing the box, and discarding it as filler.  This could explain why they are out of stock (or, as TheBrickBlogger's answer indicates, they are popular items like the Cave Troll).

After discovering the capes, I've cancelled my replacement order.  I provided feedback to LEGO recommending they make the container box more obvious.

Comment: Lesson learned: Never let anything from the box out of your sight until the model is completed.

Answer (score 4):

I have not heard of this problem before and I'm a member of several LEGO communities. However it is quite possibe that a batch is missing the parts, or even just your one box. I would suggest that instead of trying to get the replacement parts online, just call customer service and get them that way. Perhaps they are holding back on online stock because they want to make sure that real replacement issues get taken care of before someone buys the parts as extras. Those little capes are quite popular. ;)